# How to hide area on button location with video-js?

Tags: css, video.js

In my app with bootstrap 4.2 I use video-js, having included :

I want to customize video using video-js lib view button, what I do with style :

```
 .video-js .vjs-big-play-button .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {
     content: "";
     background-image: url('/images/video-js-icon.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 66px;
     background-position: 55% calc(50% - 0px);
     border: none !important;
     margin-left: 80px !important;
     box-shadow: none !important;
 }
```

It works, but I need to hide  area on button location : https://prnt.sc/UyePVgJzQFuw

How can I do it ?

Comment: have you tried setting the `opacity` to 0 and `visibility` to hidden for the `.vjs-big-play-button`?

Comment: In this caserboth areas are not visible. I need to hide only 1

Comment: then try add the property `display: none` to `.video-js .vjs-big-play-button .vjs-icon-placeholder`

Comment: try this, after your code, if it doesn't work let me know details

 `.vjs-big-play-button {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: with display: none; -nothing happens and I see both areas.  with visibility : hidden; option both areas are not visible. I need to see only my custom icon